# TFS post build powershell script not seeing commands from imported module

Tags: powershell, tfs, dynamics-crm-2011

We have a TFS build process using a custom template.  The build works fine with the crm solution files successfully being created.  We are then attempting to run a powershell script on the post build.  This script imports a module.  But the commands in the module are not being exposed.  Whenever we attempt to invoke a command, we get an error. Along the lines of

> The term 'Get-XrmSolution' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program.

It doesn't matter which command we use in that module, we get the same kind of error.

To troubleshoot, we have logged onto the build server under the identity of the build account and can successfully run the script we are attempting to run.

Putting some more output into the script to troubleshoot...

`Get-Module` lists Xrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.  - Good.

`Get-Command -Module "Xrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell"` returns nothing.  From the console, a number of commands are listed.

Is there something we need to do with the running of powershell post build scripts to enable the contents of an imported module to be seen?

Comment: Does the module load from a 32-bit PowerShell process or is it 64-bit specific? Keep in mind that VS is 32-bit and is likely launching the 32-bit version of PowerShell.

Comment: Does that mean that a TFS build will run a 32 bit PowerShell process?  That could be relevant.  The module we're loading will be 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks Keith. That sent us down a certain track of troubleshooting.  Changed the MSBuildPlatform from Auto to X86 in the Build process parameters and all was good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch out for the bitness of PowerShell invoked by MSBuild and likewise, the bitness of MSBuild launched by Visual Studio.  Certain modules only run in either 32-bit or 64-bit PowerShell and not both.  You want to make sure the correct version of  PowerShell is getting launched.

Comment: How do you do this? I am having the same problem and I want to run my script in 32-bit PowerShell

Comment: If you need to launch 32-bit PowerShell from a 64-bit msbuild use the path `$(WinDir)\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

Comment: I get that, which is great. I'm just not sure where to make this call. Do I just place it directly at the beginning of my script?

Comment: If this is from a MSBuild file then it would be in `<Exec Command="$(WinDir) \SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe myscript.ps1"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you have to explicitly import the module with no assumption of being loaded on user profile, nor on the script path.
Suppose Module1.psm1 is in the same folder as your script, use something like

```
Import-Module (Join-Path (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition) 'Module1.psm1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The module was loaded in the 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules' folder (64 bits).

It all seemed fine when I logged on as the user, but it failed during TFS build.

Solution: I had to uninstall the module in PowerShell 64 bit and re-install in PowerShell 32 bit.

The module was then installed in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules' folder.